# Looping to set labelname and label text

Tags: for-loop, datetimepicker, label, tablelayoutpanel

I have a calendar that I'm working on setting up.  I have a loop that I have constructed but can't seem to get it to work.  Can someone help.

I have labels that are d1-d42.

```cs
public void schSetDates()
        {
            var Eom = scheduledatepicker.Value.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
            Label d = new Label();
            if (scheduledatepicker.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                for (int l = 1; l <= Eom.Day; l++)
                {
                    for (int i = 1-1; i <= Eom.Day; i++)
                    {
                        d.Name = ("d" + l.ToString("dd"));
                        d.Text = scheduledatepicker.Value.AddDays(i++).ToString("dd");
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? It is not clear at all. Your code looks wrong because you create only one label and it only contains the loop occurence. It looks like you want to create several labels : in this case, move the `Label d = new Label();` in your loop (before `d.Name = ...`). And you have to add your labels to another control to see them.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement as the following instead of `d.Name = "..."`.

Define label `Label d;` outside for loop. And you can retrieve each label by using the following method. Here assumed your label names are like d01, d02, d03..... d42.

```
d = this.Controls.Find("d" + l.ToString("D2"), true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
```